# Why are all "non-swinging" representations self-dual?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple (say complex) Lie algebra, and $V$ an irreducible finite-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{g}$. Denote by $w_0$ the longest element of the Weyl group, i.e. the unique element that sends the dominant Weyl chamber to its negative. We say that the representation $V$ is:

- *radical* if $V$ has zero as a weight.
- *non-swinging* if $V$ has no $w_0$-invariant weights, except possibly for the zero weight. (I introduced this terminology in https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03833 . If anyone knows some other name for this property, I am all ears!)
- *self-dual* if the highest weight of $V$ (or, equivalently, the set of all weights of $V$; or, equivalently, the character of $V$) is $-w_0$-invariant.

Now it so happens that **all non-swinging radical representations are actually self-dual**. However the only way in which I know how to prove this is essentially by exhaustive enumeration.

Namely, one can easily reduce to the case where $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple. Then, if I am not mistaken:

- In types $A_n$ with $n \geq 2$ and $E_6$, the only radical non-swinging representation is the adjoint one.
- In type $D_{2n+1}$, the only radical non-swinging representations are the representations $\Lambda^{2k} \mathbb{C}^{2n+1}$, for $k = 1, \ldots, n$; these are all self-dual by inspection. (Their highest weights are respectively $\varpi_2, \varpi_4, \ldots, \varpi_{2n-2}, \varpi_{2n} + \varpi_{2n+1}$.)
- In the remaining types,  $w_0 = -\operatorname{Id}$ so all representations are automatically non-swinging and self-dual.

But actually proving that these lists are exhaustive is moderately painful, especially for $E_6$; I would like to avoid it if possible. Does anyone see a more elegant argument?

Comment: Do you have any other good characterisations of when a representation is swinging/non-swinging? I thought perhaps that $\omega + w_0\omega$, for $\omega$ the highest weight, would give a swinging weight but alas it is not always among the representation's weights even if we restrict to radical representations (whose weights lie on the root lattice of course)

Comment: No, I do not. But I would love to have one!

Comment: I tried to do some experiments of this kind. For each swinging highest weight, I know (on a case-by-case basis) how to find a $-w_0$-invariant weight of the corresponding representation. If there were some sort of uniform description of that weight, that would basically solve the problem... But I fail to see any such uniform description. For instance take $G = SL_3$, $\omega = 3\varpi_1 = (2,-1,-1)$. Then the *unique* $-w_0$-invariant weight is $(-1,2,-1)$, which is on the "opposite side" of the picture...

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment. That seems to be backwards to the the original question. Do we not want something like: for a highest weight $\omega$, which is not $-w_0$-invariant (i.e. non-self-dual rep) find a weight in the corresponding representation which is $w_0$-invariant (i.e. swinging)? Either way $3\varpi_1$ should not be swinging if I have understood correctly as $w_0(3\varpi_1) = -3\varpi_2$ or do you mean it is the highest weight of a swinging representation?

Comment: Oh, sorry, indeed I wrote some nonsense! Let me try again. For each non-self-dual (and not "swinging") highest weight $\omega$, we want to find some nonzero $w_0$-invariant (and not "$-w_0$-invariant") weight somewhere in the corresponding representation. So, I agree with you, a natural attemt is to try to find it somewhere between $\omega$ and $w_0 \omega$. But for $\omega = 3\varpi_1$, the only such weight is $(-1, 2, -1)$, which is "on the other side": i.e. $\omega$ and $w_0 \omega$ are two vertices of the big triangle, and $(-1, 2, -1)$ is the third one.

Comment: "do you mean it is the highest weight of a swinging representation?" -> yes, this is what I had in mind, but even like this it was wrong, see above.